# regex for finding gene product from the text

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

What regex should I use for matching such text

```
/product="hypothetical protein"".
```

by far I have tired this pattern:

```py
x = re.match(r"^s*\\=product(.*)",line)"
```

Comment: You should expand your question to be an [mcve] with example input and expected output. What are you expecting to capture?

Comment: try: "\/product=\"([\w ]*)\""

Comment: Your pattern `^s*\\=product(.*)` matches optional `s` chars, and then `\=product` which is not in the example string. Did you mean `^/product="[^"]+"` https://regex101.com/r/wKcVlp/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
test_str = ' /product="hypothetical protein"'
match = re.search(r'product="([^"]+)"', test_str)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/2IUNfa/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  product="                'product="'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
```